# rendering data on the fly using react

Tags: reactjs

I get JSON and i need to render it in webview using react js. The issue is on making the call i get, say 100 product details in JSON and i will be able to render only 6 at a time on the screen but still i have to wait till all 100 JSON data is being fetched . This increases the response time. I want to say, fetch 10 product details and fetch more as the user scrolls down as it increases the efficiency. Even in pagination the entire data is loaded initially and is given smooth scrolling.

Comment: You could try the `react-infinite` component. You give it an initial subset of data, and a callback function where you load another subset every time the user reaches the end of your results. https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite

Answer (score 0):

By saying fetch you mean fetching from the JSON server right? If that's the case you might want to tweak your server to support pagination.